# Unable to print with MigraDoc/PDFsharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, migradoc

I added the NuGet packages to my project:

> PDFsharp + MigraDoc
>
> Version: 1.50.4790-beta5a (Prerelease)

That added the References:

> MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel
>
> MigraDoc.Rendering
>
> MigraDoc.RtfRendering
>
> PdfSharp
>
> PdfSharp.Charting

I am using VS2013, targeting .NET Framework 4.5.

There's no **MigraDocPrintDocument** class/namespace, nor **Printing.MigraDocPrintDocument**...

Also I've tried to add a **PagePreview** control to my Form (I'm developing a Windows.Forms application) but there is no such control nor can I add such item to my toolbox from the dlls/packages.

I have made the PDF document pretty straight-forward, but now I'm stuck with this last step and I can't see the light. Need to print out to a thermal-printer.

A short snippet of my code:

```
public void PrintMigraDoc(Bitmap ImagenBMP, string nombre, string apellido, string documento, string nacimiento, string nacionalidad, string grupo)
{
    //Save image in greyscale
    Bitmap bmp = GrayScale(ImagenBMP);
    bmp.Save("foto_grey.bmp");
    
    //Create document
    Document document = new Document();
    //Custom Normal Style
    Style style = document.Styles["Normal"];
    style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
    style.Font.Size = 6;

    //Sections & Page Properties
    Section section = document.AddSection();
    Unit width, height;
    width = Unit.FromMillimeter(60);
    height = Unit.FromMillimeter(100);
    section.PageSetup.PageWidth = width;
    section.PageSetup.PageHeight = height;
    section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 5;
    section.PageSetup.RightMargin = 5;
    section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 5;

    //Fecha
    Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph(DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd") + ", " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
    //Foto
    paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
    MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image imagen = section.AddImage("foto_grey.bmp");
    imagen.Width = "2.5cm";
    imagen.LockAspectRatio = true;
    imagen.Left = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ShapePosition.Center;

    paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

    //Datos en Tabla
    this.table = section.AddTable();
    this.table.Borders.Width = 0.25;
    this.table.Borders.Left.Width = 0.5;
    this.table.Borders.Right.Width = 0.5;
    this.table.Rows.LeftIndent = 0;
    this.table.RightPadding = 0;
    //Columnas
    MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Column column = this.table.AddColumn();
    column = this.table.AddColumn();
    //Filas
    MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Row row = table.AddRow();
    //Nombre
    paragraph = row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Name: ");
    paragraph.AddFormattedText(nombre, TextFormat.Bold);
    row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 1;
    //Apellido
    row = table.AddRow();
    paragraph = row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Surename: ");
    paragraph.AddFormattedText(apellido, TextFormat.Bold);
    row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 1;
    //Documento
    row = table.AddRow();
    paragraph = row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Document: ");
    paragraph.AddFormattedText(documento, TextFormat.Bold);
    row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 1;
    //Apellido
    row = table.AddRow();
    paragraph = row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Birth Date: ");
    paragraph.AddFormattedText(nacimiento, TextFormat.Bold);
    paragraph = row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Nationality: ");
    paragraph.AddFormattedText(nacionalidad, TextFormat.Bold);

                    
    PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(false);
    pdfRenderer.Document = document;
    pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();
    string filename = "Invoice.pdf";
    pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(filename);

        

    // Creates a PrintDocument that simplyfies printing of MigraDoc documents
    //MigraDocPrintDocument printDocument = new MigraDocPrintDocument();
       
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a preview, try `PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF` or `PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI`.

Check the `Document Viewer` sample:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/DocumentViewer-sample.ashx

You can download the complete sample code here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/pdfsharp/PDFsharp%201.50%20%28beta%203%29/

If you want to print, take the printing class from an earlier version. See also:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3202
You will need the GDI build for printing.

Comment: Thank you! that link to the post solved my problem of printing. **Using GDI+ and adding MigraDocPrintDocument.cs to my project**. Now I will look for the Document Viewer you suggest as well. But the main issue was solved so I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: The DocumentViewer was easy to use. It is a control in the GDI library.